# Dynamically Generating XML Deserialization Classes / Code: Part I, Reading

Tags: java, object-oriented, parsing, plugin

I'm building an IntelliJ Plugin which will allow a person to select an XML file (and even a snippet of XML in the file, if they like) and, using a really brief GUI, generate classes / code in one of a selection of languages that will read the XML via native functions and generate code to do so on a regular basis.

The idea here is that a user should be able to generate a deserialization function that would not rely on any third-party libraries, but only on the native built-in features of the language and framework. Additionally, this would mean no reflection / introspection would be necessary: just read the XML into a fully strong-typed thing.

I'm going to post this as several "parts", because it's a large project. I'll do so incrementally: starting from the first component and moving towards the last.

The first step in the adventure is to create and use a `Parser` which can read our XML file into some nodes / objects. The idea here is that it *only* cares about the structure of the file: node names, keys, and value **types**, not the actual values. (So `<node attr="test">` would say "this is a node named 'node', with an attribute named 'attr', that is a string.")

To start with, we should begin at the, well, beginning: reading the file.

For simplicity, I've built a `Reading` class that can take a document as a string and attempt to parse the XML out of it:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = Reading.readDocument(document);
```

This is a very simple interface, but underneath it starts doing a lot of work:

```
package Xml;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Reading {
    public static ArrayList<Node> readDocument(String document) throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(document));
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        int indentation = 0;

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                Node node = new Node(startElement.getName().getLocalPart());

                Iterator attributes = startElement.getAttributes();
                while (attributes.hasNext()) {
                    Attribute attribute = (Attribute)attributes.next();
                    if (attribute.isSpecified()) {
                        node.add_attribute(attribute.getName().getLocalPart(), attribute.getValue());
                    }
                }

                ArrayList<Node> nodeAddition = getActiveNode(nodes, indentation);
                nodeAddition.add(node);
                indentation++;
            } else if (event.isCharacters()) {
                Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
                String data = characters.getData();

                ArrayList<Node> nodeAddition = getActiveNode(nodes, indentation - 1);
                nodeAddition.get(nodeAddition.size() - 1).set_value(data);
            } else if (event.isEndElement()) {
                indentation--;
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Node> getActiveNode(ArrayList<Node> nodes, int indentation) {
        ArrayList<Node> nodeAddition = nodes;

        while (indentation > 0) {
            indentation--;
            nodeAddition = nodeAddition.get(nodeAddition.size() - 1).get_nodes();
        }

        return nodeAddition;
    }
}
```

Here, we read the XML in and start processing it into our list of array nodes. We keep the nested node structure, and we have the following definition of a `Node` within our program:

```
package Xml;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Node {
    private String _name;
    private String _value;
    private ArrayList<Node> _nodes;
    private HashMap<String, String> _attributes;

    public Node(String name) {
        _name = name;
        _nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        _attributes = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String get_name() {
        return _name;
    }

    public String get_value() {
        return _value;
    }

    public void set_value(String _value) {
        this._value = _value;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> get_attributes() {
        return _attributes;
    }

    public void add_attribute(String key, String value) {
        _attributes.put(key, value);
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> get_nodes() {
        return _nodes;
    }
}
```

Obviously we're reading the value in here, but we'll eliminate that later. *That* was the easy part.

Next, we need to parse the nodes into some type of "object", here we'll use our `Parser` to begin doing some *real* work:

```
Parser parser = new Parser();                
parser.set_integerRule(getIntegerRule(wrapper.getSelectedNumberRule()));
parser.set_nullDefault(wrapper.getUseStringForNull() ? Type.STRING : Type.NULL);
parser.set_dateFormat(wrapper.getDateFormat());         
parser.set_allNodesAreArrays(wrapper.getAllNodesAreArrays());
for (Tuple2<String, String> rule : wrapper.getBooleanRules()) {
    parser.add_booleanRule(new ParserBooleanRule(rule.getFirst(), rule.getSecond()));
}
ArrayList<CodeObject> codeObjects = parser.parse(nodes);
```

The `Parser` is *much* more complex, and has a lot more going on. To start: it has a selection of "rules" that determine how and why it parses things, particularly how to handle different "features" of our parser. We have a few major features:

1. **Number Rules**: when the parser encounters a number type, how should it treat the type? We can use the minimal data-size, or we can assume the minimum is `Int`, `Long`, or `Double`.
2. **Use String for Null**: when the parser encounters a null value, how should it proceed? If selected, the parser should intrinsically treat the lack of a value as a `String`.
3. **Date Format**: how should the parser detect dates? If specified, the parser should use the specified format to detect date types.
4. **Boolean Rules**: how should the parser detect true/false values? Three built-in rules exist for true/false respectively: `Y`/`N`, `Yes`/`No`, `True`/`False`.
5. **Result Language**: this is less for the parser, and more for the generator. What is the destination output language?

So, with that said, we'll look at the `Parser`:

```
package Generation;

import Xml.Node;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Parser {
    private String _dateFormat;
    private ParserIntegerRule _integerRule;
    private Type _nullDefault;
    private ArrayList<ParserBooleanRule> _booleanRules;
    private boolean _allNodesAreArrays;

    public Parser() {
        _integerRule = ParserIntegerRule.Minimal;
        _nullDefault = Type.NULL;
        _booleanRules = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String get_dateFormat() { return _dateFormat; }
    public void set_dateFormat(String _dateFormat) { this._dateFormat = _dateFormat; }
    public ParserIntegerRule get_integerRule() { return _integerRule; }
    public void set_integerRule(ParserIntegerRule _integerRule) { this._integerRule = _integerRule; }
    public Type get_nullDefault() { return _nullDefault; }
    public void set_nullDefault(Type _nullDefault) { this._nullDefault = _nullDefault; }
    public ArrayList<ParserBooleanRule> get_booleanRules() { return _booleanRules; }    
    public void add_booleanRule(ParserBooleanRule rule) { _booleanRules.add(rule); }
    public boolean is_allNodesAreArrays() { return _allNodesAreArrays; }
    public void set_allNodesAreArrays(boolean _allNodesAreArrays) { this._allNodesAreArrays = _allNodesAreArrays; }

    private Type getType(String value) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(_dateFormat);
        format.setLenient(false);

        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return _nullDefault;
        }

        if (_dateFormat != null) {
            try {
                format.parse(value);
                return Type.DATE;
            } catch (ParseException ignored) { }
        } 

        for (ParserBooleanRule rule : _booleanRules) {
            String tempValue = value.toLowerCase();
            if (tempValue.equals(rule.get_true()) || tempValue.equals(rule.get_false())) {
                return Type.BOOLEAN;
            }
        }

        if (_integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.Minimal) {
            try {
                //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                Byte.parseByte(value);
                return Type.INT8;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
        }

        if (_integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.Minimal) {
            try {
                //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                Short.parseShort(value);
                return Type.INT16;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
        }

        if (_integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.Minimal || _integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.AssumeInt) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(value);
                return Type.INT32;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
        }

        if (_integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.Minimal || _integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.AssumeInt || _integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.AssumeLong) {
            try {
                Long.parseLong(value);
                return Type.INT64;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
        }

        try {
            Double.parseDouble(value);
            return Type.DOUBLE;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }

        return Type.STRING;
    }

    private boolean isNumeric(Type type) {
        switch (type) {
            case INT8:
                return true;
            case INT16:
                return true;
            case INT32:
                return true;
            case INT64:
                return true;
            case DOUBLE:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private Type lowestCommonNumericType(Type type1, Type type2) {
        if (type1 == Type.INT8) {
            return type2;
        }
        if (type1 == Type.INT16) {
            if (type2 == Type.INT8) {
                return Type.INT16;
            }

            return type2;
        }
        if (type1 == Type.INT32) {
            if (type2 == Type.INT8 || type2 == Type.INT16) {
                return Type.INT32;
            }

            return type2;
        }
        if (type1 == Type.INT64) {
            if (type2 == Type.INT8 || type2 == Type.INT16 || type2 == Type.INT32) {
                return Type.INT64;
            }

            return type2;
        }

        return Type.DOUBLE;
    }

    private Type compareTypes(Type type1, Type type2) {
        if (type1 == Type.NULL) {
            return type2;
        }

        if (type2 == Type.NULL) {
            return type1;
        }

        if (type1 == Type.OBJECT || type2 == Type.OBJECT) {
            return Type.OBJECT;
        }

        if (_dateFormat != null
                && ((type1 == Type.DATE && isNumeric(type2))
                    || (isNumeric(type1) && type2 == Type.DATE))) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(_dateFormat);
            format.setLenient(false);
            if (isNumeric(getType(format.format(Date.from(Instant.now()))))) {
                return type1 == Type.DATE ? type2 : type1;
            }
        }

        if (type1 == Type.BOOLEAN && type2 == Type.BOOLEAN) {
            return Type.BOOLEAN;
        }

        if (type1 == Type.DATE && type2 == Type.DATE) {
            return Type.DATE;
        }

        if (isNumeric(type1) && isNumeric(type2)) {
            return lowestCommonNumericType(type1, type2);
        }

        return Type.STRING;
    }

    private CodeObject objectWithName(Collection<CodeObject> codeObjects, String name) {
        for (CodeObject codeObject : codeObjects) {
            if (codeObject.get_name().equals(name)) {
                return codeObject;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    private ArrayList<CodeObject> getMainObjects(@NotNull ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        ArrayList<CodeObject> codeObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Node node : nodes) {
            CodeObject object = new CodeObject(node.get_name());
            codeObjects.add(object);

            HashMap<String, String> attributes = node.get_attributes();
            for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
                CodeObject attrCodeObject = new CodeObject(key, getType(attributes.get(key)));
                object.add_object(attrCodeObject);
                attrCodeObject.set_from(From.ATTRIBUTE);
            }

            ArrayList<Node> subNodes = node.get_nodes();
            if (subNodes.size() == 0) {
                object.set_type(getType(node.get_value()));
                object.set_from(attributes.size() > 0 ? From.NODE : From.VALUE);

                if (node.get_value() != null) {
                    Type myAttrType = getType(attributes.get("_Text"));
                    if (myAttrType == Type.NULL) {
                        myAttrType = Type.STRING;
                    }

                    CodeObject attrCodeObject = new CodeObject("_Text", myAttrType);
                    object.add_object(attrCodeObject);
                    attrCodeObject.set_from(From.RAW_VALUE);
                }
            } else {
                object.add_objects(getMainObjects(subNodes));
                object.set_from(From.NODE);
            }

            if (attributes.size() > 0 || subNodes.size() > 0) {
                object.set_type(Type.OBJECT);
            }
        }

        return codeObjects;
    }

    private void reduceObjects(@NotNull CodeObject existing, @NotNull CodeObject object) {
        existing.set_type(compareTypes(existing.get_type(), object.get_type()));
        existing.set_isArray(existing.is_isArray() || object.is_isArray());
        ArrayList<CodeObject> reducedObjects = reduceObjects(object.get_codeObjects());

        for (CodeObject reducedObject : reducedObjects) {
            CodeObject existingSubObject = objectWithName(existing.get_codeObjects(), reducedObject.get_name());
            if (existingSubObject == null) {
                existing.add_object(reducedObject);
                continue;
            }

            reduceObjects(existingSubObject, reducedObject);
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    private ArrayList<CodeObject> reduceObjects(@NotNull ArrayList<CodeObject> objects) {
        ArrayList<CodeObject> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (CodeObject object : objects) {
            CodeObject existingObject = objectWithName(result, object.get_name());
            if (existingObject == null) {
                existingObject = new CodeObject(object.get_name(), object.get_type());
                existingObject.set_from(object.get_from());
                existingObject.set_isArray((_allNodesAreArrays && existingObject.get_from() == From.NODE) || object.is_isArray());
                existingObject.add_objects(reduceObjects(object.get_codeObjects()));
                result.add(existingObject);
            } else {
                existingObject.set_isArray(true);
                object.set_isArray(true);
                reduceObjects(existingObject, object);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @NotNull
    public ArrayList<CodeObject> parse(@NotNull ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        ArrayList<CodeObject> objects = getMainObjects(nodes);
        return reduceObjects(objects);
    }
}
```

This class is somewhat long, and has a few other definitions we need to include:

The `CodeObject`:

```
package Generation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class CodeObject {
    private String _name;
    private Type _type;
    private From _from;
    private boolean _isArray;
    private ArrayList<CodeObject> _codeObjects;

    public CodeObject(String name) {
        _name = name;
        _codeObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public CodeObject(String name, Type type) {
        this(name);
        _type = type;
    }

    public String get_name() {
        return _name;
    }

    public Type get_type() {
        return _type;
    }

    public void set_type(Type _type) {
        this._type = _type;
    }

    public ArrayList<CodeObject> get_codeObjects() {
        return _codeObjects;
    }

    public void add_object(CodeObject codeObject) {
        _codeObjects.add(codeObject);
    }

    public void add_objects(Collection<CodeObject> codeObject) {
        _codeObjects.addAll(codeObject);
    }

    public From get_from() {
        return _from;
    }

    public void set_from(From _from) {
        this._from = _from;
    }

    public boolean is_isArray() {
        return _isArray;
    }

    public void set_isArray(boolean _isArray) {
        this._isArray = _isArray;
    }
}
```

The `Type`:

```
package Generation;

public enum Type {
    NULL,
    STRING,
    INT8,
    INT16,
    INT32,
    INT64,
    DOUBLE,
    DATE,
    BOOLEAN,
    OBJECT
}
```

The `From`:

```
package Generation;

public enum From {
    ATTRIBUTE,
    NODE,
    VALUE,
    RAW_VALUE
}
```

The `ParserBooleanRule`:

```
package Generation;

public class ParserBooleanRule {
    private String _true;
    private String _false;

    public ParserBooleanRule(String _true, String _false) {
        this._true = _true;
        this._false = _false;
    }

    public String get_true() {
        return _true;
    }

    public String get_false() {
        return _false;
    }
}
```

And the `ParserIntegerRule`:

```
package Generation;

public enum ParserIntegerRule {
    Minimal,
    AssumeInt,
    AssumeLong,
    AssumeDouble
}
```

All these components, together, implement the logic of the parser. Read the `Node` objects into a `CodeObject` array.

Additionally, one should note all of the `Type` functions in the `Parser`: these help determine type-rules: given two types, which type should the result be? We use these to determine what we need to do with the data-types, and how an attribute of `5` and `14.2` and `test` should be compared, to get the lowest-common type: the one that will accurately represent all values in our input.

Finally, the generation also has three more components relevant to this parser:

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, ParserIntegerRule> _parserIntegerRules;

public GenerateAction() {
    super("Hello");

    _parserIntegerRules = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    _parserIntegerRules.put("Minimal", ParserIntegerRule.Minimal);
    _parserIntegerRules.put("Assume Int", ParserIntegerRule.AssumeInt);
    _parserIntegerRules.put("Assume Long", ParserIntegerRule.AssumeLong);
    _parserIntegerRules.put("Assume Double", ParserIntegerRule.AssumeDouble);
}    

@NotNull
private ParserIntegerRule getIntegerRule(String rule) {
    return _parserIntegerRules.getOrDefault(rule, ParserIntegerRule.Minimal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Program to Interfaces, not Implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384067/8339141)

The code base heavily depends on `ArrayList`. For example in `Reading`

> ```java
> ArrayList<Node> readDocument(String document) throws XMLStreamException {
>    // ..
>    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>()
>    // ..
>        ArrayList<Node> nodeAddition = getActiveNode(nodes, indentation)
> }
>
> private static ArrayList<Node> getActiveNode(ArrayList<Node> nodes, int indentation) { /* .. */ }
> ```

The only methods that are used on that instances of `ArrayList` are `add`, `get` and `size`.

> ```java
> nodeAddition.add(node);
> ```
>
> ```java
> nodeAddition.get(nodeAddition.size() - 1)//..
> ```

Since only methods get used that are defined on the interface [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), your code should rather depend on the interface than on the implementation:

```java
List<Node> readDocument(String document) throws XMLStreamException {
    // ..
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>()
    // ..
        List<Node> nodeAddition = getActiveNode(nodes, indentation)
}

private static List<Node> getActiveNode(List<Node> nodes, int indentation) { /* .. */ }
```

With *program to interfaces, not implementations* you do not limit your self to a concrete implementation, because now it would be easier to switch from an `ArrayList` to a `LinkedList` because of the use of the common interface.

---

## [Accessors Are Evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?AccessorsAreEvil)

> Public accessors indicate that the data and the behavior of a class are not kept together.
>
> This is seen as a an indication of higher coupling and lower coherence.

#### [Objects vs. Data Structures](https://hackernoon.com/objects-vs-data-structures-e380b962c1d2)

The "objects" `Value`, `CodeObject`, `ParserBooleanRule` and maybe more make have use of getters and setters. The are not objects in terms of oop - rather they are data structures.

In `Parser` inside the method `getType` is the following if-statement

> ```java
> if (tempValue.equals(rule.get_true()) || tempValue.equals(rule.get_false())) {
>    return Type.BOOLEAN;
> }
> ```

We can see that the `Parser` uses `rule` (`ParserBooleanRule`) as a data structure whilst it uses the methods `get_true` and `get_false` to look if a `value` is a boolean. Much better would be, when `ParserBooleanRule` knows if a `value` is a boolean:

```java
if (rule.fulfilledBy(value)) {
    return Type.BOOLEAN;
}
```

---

## [Don't Use Exceptions For Flow Control](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)

> ```java
> if (_integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.Minimal) {
>    try {
>        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
>        Byte.parseByte(value);
>        return Type.INT8;
>    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
> }
>
> if (_integerRule == ParserIntegerRule.Minimal) {
>    try {
>        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
>        Short.parseShort(value);
>        return Type.INT16;
>    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
> }
>
> // ..
> ```

At the first time I thought that the second if-statement will never be reached because it has the same condition as the first if-statement. Than I saw that you actually use an try-catch as condition.

Instead of you could check first if a value is a number trough a regex, count the number of figures and parse it to the data type you aspect..

---

## [Feature Envy](http://wiki.c2.com/?FeatureEnvySmell)

A classic [code] smell is a method that seems more interested in a class other than the one it is in. The most common focus of the envy is the data.

I already wrote that you have a lot of getter and setter methods witch makes it easy do access the data of an object. The `Parser` reads the data for many of your objects and do some logic on it - this is a Feature Envy. The object itself should do the operation and the `Parser` should only ask for it ([Tell don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html))

The following loop is inside `Parser` exist to manipulate a `CodeObject`

> ```java
> for (CodeObject object : objects) {
>    CodeObject existingObject = objectWithName(result, object.get_name());
>    if (existingObject == null) {
>        existingObject = new CodeObject(object.get_name(), object.get_type());
>        existingObject.set_from(object.get_from());
>        existingObject.set_isArray((_allNodesAreArrays && existingObject.get_from() == From.NODE) || object.is_isArray());
>        existingObject.add_objects(reduceObjects(object.get_codeObjects()));
>        result.add(existingObject);
>    } else {
>        existingObject.set_isArray(true);
>        object.set_isArray(true);
>        reduceObjects(existingObject, object);
>    }
> }
> ```

The `Parser` should request the change by an `CodeObject` or in this case by an `CodeObjectFactory`

When we look at the following method-names, we will see that they all include the class name on which they interact:

> `objectWithName`, `getMainObjects`, `reduceObjects`, `compareTypes` and `lowestCommonNumericType`

They should go into the classes envied by the `parser`.